# Mod rewrite rule not escaping the forward slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following example URL:

```
http://example.com/?search=iphone&page=2
```

To this:

```
http://example.com/search/iphone/2
```

So I have two parameters `search` and `page`:

`search` parameter can be any character and
`page` parameter can by any integer greater than `0`

I have the following rules in my htaccess to achieve the above:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /?search=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/([1-9][0-9]*)$ /?search=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When I print the `search` parameter value, I get the following:
`iphone/2`

When I print the `page` parameter value, I get nothing.

So, it seems the forward slash is not escaped but not sure if that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse your rule order so that more specific patter appears first and more importantly avoid use of  `.*` as it matches everything:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([1-9][0-9]*)/?$ /?search=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I need to allow all characters and I will sanitize data on my own. This is search so I can't limit to certain characters. Can you please modify to allow all characters?